# NotificationListenerService Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Can NotificationListenerService be used on android wear? orb is there some sort of listener that can listen for calls or notifications within the wearable?

Answer (score 1):

Generally what I would do is have a phone and a wear app, have the phone app register the listener and do whatever needs to be done, then send a message to the wear device to take whatever action needs to be done there.

The goal is to offload as much as possible onto the phone app and have the wear app simply respond.

Comment: Thanks but, to cut a long story short, what i am trying to achieve is, knowing which device accepted an incoming call. Was the incoming call accepted via the wearable? or the handheld? if i can detect where a call was accepted by having a listener on the handheld or by having a listener on the wearable device to know that there is an incoming call.

Comment: That is not going to be possible as the pendingIntent fired from the action is the same regardless of which device sent it.

Comment: Ok so what your saying is the default android dialler app is sending a PendingIntent to the wearable, and because of this, there is no way for me to listen for such events?

Comment: the pending intent is sent via the notification. whether its activated via the watch or the phone, the pending intent is the same. there is no difference between when a notification action is triggered on a peripheral or the phone.

Comment: Cheers, but if the pending intent is sent via a notification, what if i have a NotificationsListener on the wearable app (which is what i am trying to achieve but i cannot get it to listen in) so if a notification is sent from the handheld, the wearable NotificationListener should at leaf pickup notifications?

Comment: then you can see when the notification comes in. still does nothing to help you towards your goal. just because you know there is a notification doesnt mean that you know what happens to it.

Comment: i see. Cheers, that cleared up my understanding. I guess there is no PhoneStateListner equivalent for the wear side of things?